# How do I query nodegroups and file_roots on salt-master?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a few `nodegroups` set in a separate `master.d/*.conf` file and can correctly target them. I was wondering if there is a mechanism on the salt master to list `nodegroups` and their members without having to look through the master file or `master.d/*.conf` files. Is there a way to list `file_roots` too without having to look through files?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure that there is some way to get nodegroup file contents, but there are some methods to look into file_roots content:

> salt-run fileserver.file_list

should run on the master.
There are some similar commands, i'm not sure which one you exactly need.

> salt-run fileserver.dir_list
>
> salt-run fileserver.envs

you can see more about salt-run through the [document](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/runners/all/)